# Disjunctive Normal Form and satisfiable is in P (DNFSAT)

Tags: computer-science, computation-theory, computability

I am reading that a language that is in Disjunctive Normal Form and is satisfiable is a language in P, but there is no explanation, could anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

To make an expression that is in DNF be true, you just need to make a single disjunctive clause of it true.  A typical clause would be something like `A ^ B ^ ~C` or something like that, and so you set A and B to true and C to false.

So the algorithm would be:

1. Find some disjunctive clause that is not self-contradictory.  (I.e. it contains both X and ~X).
2. If all the disjunctive clauses contain some self-contradiction, then the entire expression cannot be satisfied.
3. If there is even one clause that doesn't self-contradict, then there is an obvious assignment of variables that makes that clause be true.  In that case the entire expression is true.

Comment: So what you have to do is to make an algorithm that solves the problem? If yes, how do you know that the algorithm you presented is in P?

Comment: Do you understand what it means for an algorithm to be in P?  Each of these steps is trivial and can be done in linear time.